# How to write the loop in this expression

Tags: c++, recursion

The expression is 1 - x^2 * (1/3 - x^2/2 * (1/5 - x^2/3 * (1/7 - ...) ) )
I wrote the program in a way so that you can input the values of x and N

```
int k=0

double expression(double x, int k, int N)
if(k>N) return 0;
return 1/(2*k+1)-x*x/(k+1)*expression(x,k+1,N);
```

The problem is the loop will calculate like 
 1 - (x^2 * 1/3) - (x^2/2 * 1/5) - (x^2/3 * 1/7) - ...

How to change my code to make it work?

Comment: You should be clearer in proposing your questions, choosing the tags and in writing the question and code as well

Comment: it is a c++. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Yo homie, You changed your code copying from the answers and playing a good guy now, eh ?

Comment: i just try to change the k-1 to k+1 to make less confusion about my problem ask

Comment: Concerning the loop, your code looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
double expression(double x2, int k, int N){
    if(k>N)
        return 0;
    return 1.0/(2*k+1)-x2/(k+1)*expression(x2,k+1,N);
}

double funct(double x, int N){
    int k=0;
    double x2 = x * x;
    return expression(x2, k, N);
}
```

notice the fact that `1` should be `1.0` so to avoid integer division.

Comment: i think the expression is like 1.0 - x^2 * 1/3 - x^2/2 * 1/5 - x^2/3 * 1/7 - ... or i understand it wrong?

Comment: try it! I corrected a typo in `expressio(x2, k, N)`

Comment: try both of it but it seems it gives the same result

Comment: What do you expect `funct(0.7071067811865476, 2)` to return?  I expect `0.858333` which is 1.0 - 0.5(1/3 - 1/20).

Comment: i get the result 0.5757945360 by inputting  funct(0.7071067811865476, 2)

Comment: i expect to get the result 0.303466660245

Comment: `funct(0.7071067811865476, 2)` should return `0.858333`. You are doing something wrong.

Comment: So it is 1 - x^2 * (1/3 - x^2/2 * (1/5) while x is 0.7071067811865476, It should be 0.858333.  But when i put in the program, the value change to 0.814297423

Comment: Pay attention to `double x2 = x * x;` please! I bet you have `double x2 = x;` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For given expression **1 - x^2 * (1/3 - x^2/2 * (1/5 - x^2/3 * (1/7 - ...) ) )** 
You want to calculate **x*x/(k+1)*innersum()** first. Just put the expression in braces and it'll be good to go. Also It'll be `k+1` instead of `k-1`.

```
int k=0

double expression(double x, int k, int N)
if(k>N) return 1;
return 1/(2*k+1)-x*x*(1/(k+1)*expression(x,k+1,N));
```

Comment: Thanks you for trying to help me, but i think your code will calculate 1-(x^2*1/3-(x^2/2*1/5-(....

Comment: It seems that when i input different values of n, it gives out the same answer.

Comment: Can you share some test cases.?

Comment: If i enter the value of x as 2, and i enter the value of n be 2 or 200, it still give me the same result